# mmap write followed by flush does not seem to write to disk

Tags: python

I want the following to replace the binary string `\x01\x02\x03` in the file `test.bin` with the binary string `\x04\x05\x06`.  When I run the script it runs without error.  However, when I run `cmp -bl test.bin test.bin.old` (where `test.bin.old` is an unmodified copy of the original file) then I get nothing (i.e. `test.bin` has not been modified).  What's wrong please?

```
#!/usr/bin/python
import mmap

filename = "test.bin"

with open(filename, "r+b") as f:
    mm = mmap.mmap(f.fileno(), 0, mmap.ACCESS_WRITE)
    oldstr = '\x01\x02\x03'
    foundpos = mm.find(oldstr)
    if foundpos == -1:
        print "Could not find string to replace"
        exit(-1)
    mm.seek(foundpos)
    mm.write('\x04\x05\x06')
    mm.flush()
    mm.close()
    f.close()
    exit(0)
```